# Play MMS stream with an embeded Flash player

Tags: flash, streaming, vlc-media-player, mms-streaming

I'm using VLC player to stream an MMS audio stream for a radio and I would like to incorporate a Flash player on the site to listen to the radio instead of letting Windows Media Player handle it.

Is it possible? I can't find any Flash players that seem to support this kind of streaming..

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible, Flash doesn't support the mms:// protocol.